# How do I use the index value of an array and pass it to a HTML modal so I can show the data there without using a loop in angular 7

Tags: html, angular, typescript

How do I use the index value of an array and pass it to a HTML modal so I can show the data there without using a loop in angular 7

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../services/api.service';
import { movieModel } from '../models/movie';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.less']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  movies:movieModel[];
  constructor(public api:ApiService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
      this.loadMovies();
  }
      

loadMovies(): void {
    this.movies = [];
    this.api.getMovies().subscribe(
    data =>
    {
        this.movies = data.results;
        this.movies = this.movies.slice(0 , 5);
        console.log(this.movies);
     }
  );
 }
}
```

```html
<h1>Top 5 Movies by the New York Times</h1>
<div class="uk-child-width-1-3@s uk-grid-match" uk-grid>
    <div *ngFor="let movie of movies;  let i = index">
        <div class="uk-card uk-card-hover uk-card-body">
            <h3 class="uk-card-title">{{movie.display_title}}</h3>
            <span>Headline: {{movie.headline}}</span><br/>
            <span>Summary: {{movie.summary_short | characters:150 }}</span><br/><button class="uk-button uk-button-default" uk-toggle="target: #my-id">Read More</button><br/>
            <p>By: {{movie.byline}}<br/>Rating:{{mpaa_rating || NA}}<br/>Date of Release: {{movie.publication_date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="my-id" uk-modal>
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog uk-modal-body">
        <h2 class="uk-modal-title">Summary</h2>
                {{movie.summary_short}}
        <button class="uk-modal-close uk-button uk-button-default" type="button">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can someone please explain to me how i get the value for movie.summary_short to work in the dialog box I have the for loop index done but cant figure out how to pass it to the other HTML element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Declare another property like `summary_short` in `component.ts`.
2. bind on `(click)` of 'Read More' button to assign `movie.summary_short` to `summary_short`.

**component.html**

```html
<button (click)="saveSummary(movie.summary_short)" class="uk-button uk-button-default" uk-toggle="target: #my-id">
  Read More
</button>
...
<div id="my-id" uk-modal>
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog uk-modal-body">
        <h2 class="uk-modal-title">Summary</h2>
                {{summary_short}}
        <button class="uk-modal-close uk-button uk-button-default" type="button">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
...
```

**component.ts**

```ts
...
summary_short
...
saveSummary(summary_short) {
  this.summary_short = summary_short
}
...
```

Comment: Hi, i defined it in the type script summary_short:string; but the console is still telling me {{summary_short }} is undefined

Comment: Have you invoked `saveSummary` method?

Comment: Sorry Im a little confused on what you mean by binding the click to assign movie.summary_short to summary_short as well as how to invoke the method im new to angular and typescript

Comment: You need to define `saveSummary` method in ts file. And add  `<button (click)="saveSummary(movie.summary_short) ...>"` in html file .

Comment: I got it working there thank you very much for your assistance

Answer (score 0):

Add a function to `Read More` button, something like this:

`<button class="uk-button uk-button-default" uk-toggle="target: #my-id" (click)="readMore(movie.summary_short)">Read More</button>`

Then in `.ts`, declare a var `modalText` and each time this button is clicked:

```
readMore(text: string){
    this.modalText = text;
}
```

Finally, in `modal`, call `{{ modalText }}`.